# passing several parameter in Jquery

Tags: jquery

```
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    $("#menu").append("<button onclick='select_food("+data[i]['id']+","+data[i]['name']+")'>Select</button>)")
}
function select_food(id, name){
     //do something
}
```

There is a syntax error on this code.
How can I pass two parameters for each button invoking select_food function?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `onclick` attributes is an outdated (and ugly) way of attaching events. Try using `data` attributes to store the information you need and attach the event with jQuery. Something like this:

```
$('#menu').on('click', 'button', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var name = $(this).data('name');

    // do something...
});

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    $("#menu").append('<button data-id="' + data[i]['id'] + '" data-name="' + data[i]['name'] + '">Select</button>')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the parameter `name` looks like a string it should be enclosed with in `""`, also you will have to make sure that the function `select_food` is available in global scope

```
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    $("#menu").append('<button onclick="select_food("' + data[i]['id'] + '","' +data[i]['name'] + '")>Select</button>)')
}
function select_food(id, name){
     //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a possible solution (see fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/gDNTw/2/):

```
$('#menu').on('click', 'button', function() 
{
    var id = this.id;
    var name = this.name;

    alert(id + ':'  + name);
    // do something...
});

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
    $("#menu").append('<button id="' + i + '" name="' + data[i] + '">Select</button>')
}
```